# split string based on character position in ORACLE 11g SQL

Tags: sql, date, oracle11g, type-conversion

I'm using oracle 11g sql developer

I have a varchar2 column with dates as 0523 (mmDD).

I want to convert them to a date column and have them look like 23-05 (dd-mm)..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can do string operations directly to get the format you want:

```
substring(c, 3, 2)||'-'||substring(c, 1, 2)
```

To convert to a date, you can use:

```
to_date('2012'||c, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

To convert a date back to the form you want:

```
to_char(<date>, 'DD-MM')
```

Comment: The solution uses c to refer to the date column you have.  || is concatenate so ||c is adding the date to the year 2012.  Not quite a full solution as you haven't given much for schema...a combination of the 3 statements here will be what you need.  +1 answer