# trying to concat a couple of TO_DATE(SUBSTR) to get a combined date of 'dd-mon-yyyy' from strings..?

Tags: sql, oracle11g, substr, concatenation, to-date

I previously ask about converting strings to dates and formatting them..
[split string based on character position in ORACLE 11g SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231161/split-string-based-on-character-position-in-oracle-11g-sql)

Here is the solution I have come up with where WKENDING is VARCHAR2 and RYEAR is date
The WKENDING has data that looks like '523'(mmdd) and RYEAR is '2012'..

```
UPDATE OB_SEL_LST84_AGG_WKEND  SET WKENDYEAR =  (TO_DATE((TO_DATE(substr(WKENDING,3,2)),'dd')||(TO_DATE(substr(WKENDING,0,1)),'mon')||(TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(RYEAR)),'yyyy')),'dd-mon-yyyy');
```

I am now getting an error 'ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis', I've double checked the parenthesis a couple of times and they look right to me.. any help would be great.. thanks!

UPDATE
- After looking at the syntax of what I have above I thought that maybe there are too many TO_DATE attempted conversions going on. So, I shortened it to this..

```
UPDATE OB_SEL_LST84_AGG_WKEND  SET WKENDYEAR =  (TO_DATE((substr(WKENDING,3,2))||(substr(WKENDING,0,1))||TO_CHAR(RYEAR)),'dd-mon-yyyy');
```

I'm still getting the missing parenthesis error though.. ARGH!

Comment: What data type is `wkendyear`?  Is it a `VARCHAR2`?  Or a `DATE`?  You seem to be trying to convert the data to a `DATE` but a `DATE` does not have a format so I'm a little confused.

Comment: @JustinCave - the data type is DATE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the data type of the `wkendyear` column is `DATE`, you should just need to

```
UPDATE OB_SEL_LST84_AGG_WKEND  
   SET wkendyear = to_date( lpad(WKENDING,4,'0') || RYEAR, 'mmddyyyy' )
```

This assumes, of course, that all your string data can be converted into a valid date.  As soon as you have a `wkending` of `0229` and a `ryear` of `2013` (or some other combination of strings that are not a valid date), the `TO_DATE` function is going to throw an exception.  That's one of the reasons that storing dates in `VARCHAR2` columns is generally problematic.

If not all of your data can be converted correctly to a `DATE`, you can create a function that attempts to do the conversion and returns a `NULL` if there is an exception.  For example

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_to_date( p_str IN VARCHAR2, p_format IN VARCHAR2 )
  RETURN DATE
IS
  l_dt DATE;
BEGIN
  l_dt := to_date( p_str, p_format );
  RETURN l_dt;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN others THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END;
```

Your `UPDATE` statement would then become

```
UPDATE OB_SEL_LST84_AGG_WKEND  
   SET wkendyear = my_to_date( lpad(WKENDING,4,'0') || RYEAR, 'mmddyyyy' )
```

You can also look for rows where the string cannot be converted to a date

```
SELECT *
  FROM OB_SEL_LST84_AGG_WKEND  
 WHERE my_to_date( lpad(WKENDING,4,'0') || RYEAR, 'mmddyyyy' ) IS NULL
   AND (wkending IS NOT NULL or ryear IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Tried your solution and got an error 'ORA-01843: not a valid month'.. thinking that its because of the varchar2 datatype?

Comment: @SeattleGray - Most likely, the problem is that some of the rows of string data cannot be converted into a valid date.  Updated my answer with code that converts the data that it can and identifies rows that have problems.

Comment: Sorry mate.. I compiled the function.. and ran the update statement you provided and then the select statement.. still no luck.. I am stumped..

Comment: just looking at the data again.. realized that your function did work.. only problem was that my data is not '0523' like I thought but '523' and the ones your function worked on were those that are like '1001' or '1101' or '1201'.. sorry, should have checked before.. So, how do I account for the missing '0'?

Comment: @SeattleGray - Assuming it is just the leading '0' that is missing, I updated my answer to pad the `wkending` to 4 characters.

Comment: Well, I gave it a try and it works great.. but now I am losing the dates that begin with something other than '0'.. how would I go about fixing that issue?

Comment: @SeattleGray - The `LPAD` call won't change a `wkending` string that has 4 characters.  Can you give an example of a string that is not working as expected?

Comment: well, it looks like I have some data issues unrelated to the problem you are helping me with.. Thanks a bunch for the help..